# OSX: Set App Icon Number

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This seems like it would be common question and I searched for it, but came up dry.

Whenever I get an email or message on Outlook, Skype, etc. OSX puts a red number over the icon with the number of messages received. How can I set this number for my own app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this link for NSDocTile class reference. You may need to sign in for it, but I am unsure about that.

[NSDocTile Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSDockTile_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

edit: the method with the name `-(void) setBadgeLabel: (NSString *) string;` looks like it may be what you want.